# How can I exclude from Gradle dependency lists after the fact?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

This is for a Maven-to-Gradle build conversion on a large build. Think Rodan, Ghidora, Godzilla, etc. Yeah. That big.

Given a dependency that looks like this:

```
ext.jbossBom = [ ... ]// This is in the root project.
compile (rootProject.ext.jbossBom) //This is not in the root project
```

How can I exclude items from the above? I've tried variants of:

```
compile (rootProject.ext.jbossBom) {
exclude group: "some.group", module: "some.module"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jbossBom` is a collection. Remove the element your want to eliminate:

```
compile (rootProject.ext.jbossBom.findAll{ !it.startsWith('some.group')})
```

To exclude a certain transitive dependency globally(irrespective of which dependency brings it in), you can do:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'commons-math3', module: 'commons-math3'
    compile.exclude group: 'commons-pool2', module: 'commons-pool2'
 }
```

To exclude a specific transitive dependency from each of the contents of `jbossBom`, you can do:

```
dependencies{
    jbossBom.each{
        compile (it){exclude group:'foo', module:'bar'}
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the first time I've asked this question and certainly this is the best answer I've seen so far but does this include something that gets brought in through transivity? Those are my problem children.  What I suspect is that I'm going to have to build a gigantic dependency map for this beast from the maven side and then rearrange it.  An exercise in pain and tedium to be sure. What if I change the nature of my lists so that they are a true tree of dependencies and try to work with them that way?

Comment: I've reviewed the API for findAll and it returns a Collection, so that means that it won't cause problems with other components that use the same dependency collection. Awesome.

Comment: This does not exclude transitives. The element you're removing will only be removed if it is already in the collection, which transitives wont be. You can however add a global exclude to the compile configuration which will exclude that transitive, however it entered the mix.

Comment: BTW, if you find the answer informative, you should upvote it. Also consider marking it as an accepted answer.http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: So the answer is: "You can't do that in Gradle yet. ...at least not to the degree necessary." ?

Comment: Not really, the answer is rarely "No you can't" with gradle, its more, how much effort are you willing to put in to get what you want :). Updated my answer, see if that helps.

Comment: If I exclude it globally that will surely break something else.

Comment: Hmm in which case, you should probably append an exclude clause to each element of your collection. What transitive are you trying to exclude? I'll update my answer in a few hours when I can get on a computer again.

Comment: OK, this is showing some real promise. :-) What you proposed lately is the best I've seen so far but how would you go about retrieving a specific dependency so that you can drill down and nail exactly the right one? Wouldn't that be ideal? I might do this in the parent project so that I can create a customized list for each sub project that requires one. Depends on what the performance hit is though.

Comment: You can add an exclude to a dependency that doesn't contain the excluded transitive - it will have no effect if the dependency does not contain the excluded transitive.

Comment: OIC, so if it isn't in a dependency block, the transitivity doesn't yet exist?

Comment: What about walking the entire tree excluding anything that's already been added to a set... or starting with a structure other than a list?

Comment: ...of course we would like to leave the very last instance of said dependency. IDK. I think the Gradle folks idea of using a List to represent dependencies was a bad idea from the get go.  A custom structure is what is needed.

Comment: I agree with you that the gradle workarounds for jbossbom is less than ideal.